# Unable to post multiple dropdown value PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am using "Multiselect dropdown",But i am facing two problems 1) Unable to send select box value 2) whenever
i click on select box then dropdown not closed,How can i fix this ?

```
<select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui fluid selection dropdown no label">
      <option value="">All</option>
       <option value="1">Health 111</option>
      <option value="2">Health 2</option>
      <option value="3">Health 3</option>
      <option value="4">Power 1</option>
      <option value="5">Power 2</option>
      <option value="6">Power 3</option>
      <option value="7">Speed 1</option>
      <option value="8">Speed 2</option>
    </select>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
$('.label.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown();

$('.no.label.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
  useLabels: false
});

$('.ui.button').on('click', function () {
  $('.ui.dropdown')
    .dropdown('restore defaults')
})

</script>
```

Comment: You need to give it an array-style name: `name="skills[]"`. Then `$_POST['skills']` will be an array of all the selected options.

Comment: @Barmar And how can i close dropdown after click on "same box" ?